# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EnvironmentLoaderListener shiro apache

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, shiro

I am trying to use Shiro Apache for users and roles management but I am not able to run the proyect and I dont know why it doesnt work.

I going to copy the error, web.xml file and shiro.ini file and pom.xml file I hope someone could help me.

**Error:**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EnvironmentLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5041)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">


  <display-name>TFG</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>loginPage.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

**shiro.ini:**

```
[main]
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager

securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Users and their (optional) assigned roles
# username = password, role1, role2, ..., roleN
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

[users]
user = 1234,gestor
user2 = 1234,editor
user3 = 1234,crearprofesor,leerusuario,editarusuario,gestor
user4 = 1234,leergrupo,profesor
user5 = 1234,CRUDPlaza
user6 = 1234,CRUDPlan
user7 = 1234,CRUDAsignatura
user6 = 1234,Sueltos

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Roles with assigned permissions
# roleName = perm1, perm2, ..., permN
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------



[roles]
profesor = *
gestor = *
CRUDUsuario = usuarios:leerusuario, usuarios:crearusuario, usuarios:borrarusuario, usuarios:editarusuario
CRUDDocente = docentes:*
CRUDGrupo = grupos:*
CRUDPlaza = plaza:*
CRUDPlan = plan:*
CRUDAsignatura = asignatura:*
Sueltos = sueltos:*
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am not sure if I have to implement EnvironmentLoaderListener class or any class that I dont have now, please, dont hesitate to contact me if you need any additional information.

Thanks.

Comment: Based on the error i understand there is a class EnvironmentLoaderListener which is not in the classpath.

Can you search in your eclipse what is the package name for this class.

Comment: Sure, but I think that the class EnviromentLoaderListernet should be in org.apache.shiro.web.env which has been added in the maven repository. https://github.com/JoseIgnacioVillegas/TFG-Gestion-Docente That´s is the entire proyect, you can check it. Thanks.

Comment: I saw the jar file it has the class what you mentioned. Worst case what i can think of is checking the WEB-INF/lib directory has the shiro-web.jar file.

Comment: But Im using Maven and I have added the dependency, is it necessary to add shiro-web.jar file too?

Comment: I didnt mean to add again. Just check in your lib directory its added or not.

Comment: I didnt add any .jar file because I added the dependencies to the pom.xml file, the question is, do I need to add .jar file to the lib directory too?

Comment: U dont need to add manually. When you create maven web project it does it automatically. You need to check your war file.

Where is your app deployed?

Comment: That is why I dont understand this error, because It suppose that "EnviromentLoaderListener" should be added automatically. I have the application in localhost, I just have the code in my github.

Comment: @Nacho, I think what @santosh-b is saying is, build the project, and check the output. (`mvn clean package`).  Also, are you running this project for the command line or only in Eclipse?